# PyQT installation -q flag

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

So I'm in the PyQT folder that I just downloaded and unzipped, and am trying to run configure.py.  I'm doing this

`alexandermoreno$ python configure.py -q  /users/alexandermoreno/QT/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake -d /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ --use-arch x86_64`

giving me the following error:

```
-bash: python configure.py -q : command not found
```

However, when I run `python configure.py` just to see its output, I get:

```
Error: Make sure you have a working Qt qmake on your PATH or use the -q
argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake.
```

So it's saying to use the -q file, but then when I use it, it gives me that the command is not found.

Comment: I don't know why but you have to use --qmake flags instead of -q. Have you already tried?

Comment: Ok, but when I did that, I got the same "command not found" python configure.py —qmake  /users/alexandermoreno/QT/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake -d /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ --use-arch x86_64
-bash: python configure.py —qmake : command not found

Comment: which pyqt version? 4 or 5?

Comment: Maybe is only this: some newline breaks your bash command in more than one piece. You paste this command from another source? You maybe run 'python configure.py -q' and nothing more ...

Comment: I think you were right lol.  Typed it by hand and it worked.